# How to complete getting substrings of a genome encoding a given amino acid sequence

Tags: c#, string

The Peptide Encoding Problem consists on Finding substrings of a genome encoding a given amino acid sequence.

The genetic code describes the translation of an RNA 3-mer (codon) into one of 20 different amino acids. The first three circles, moving from the inside out, represent the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd nucleotides of a given codon. The 4th, 5th, and 6th circles define the translated amino acid in three ways: the amino acid’s full name, its 3-letter abbreviation, and its single-letter abbreviation. Three of the 64 total RNA codons are stop codons, which halt translation and implicitly add a 21st stop symbol to the amino acid alphabet.

[image]

The problem consists on having

Input: A DNA string Text and an amino acid string Peptide.

and

Output: All substrings of Text encoding Peptide (if any such substrings exist).

```
Sample Input:
     ATGGCCATGGCCCCCAGAACTGAGATCAATAGTACCCGTATTAACGGGTGA
     MA

Sample Output:
     ATGGCC
     GGCCAT
     ATGGCC
```

the result is gotten by reading triplets so, **ATGGCC encodes MA**,  **GGCCAT** inverse would be CCGGTA written backwards so it is in fact **ATGGCC** (CCGGTA.reverse)

**the complement of genetic code is C-G, G-C, T-A and A-T**

So to solve this problem I first use already defined arrays

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;


class Program
{
    private static string[] CODONS = { 
                "TTT", "TTC", "TTA", "TTG", "TCT",
                "TCC", "TCA", "TCG", "TAT", "TAC", "TGT", "TGC", "TGG", "CTT",
                "CTC", "CTA", "CTG", "CCT", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG", "CAT", "CAC",
                "CAA", "CAG", "CGT", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "ATT", "ATC", "ATA",
                "ATG", "ACT", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG", "AAT", "AAC", "AAA", "AAG",
                "AGT", "AGC", "AGA", "AGG", "GTT", "GTC", "GTA", "GTG", "GCT",
                "GCC", "GCA", "GCG", "GAT", "GAC", "GAA", "GAG", "GGT", "GGC",
                "GGA", "GGG", };

    private static  string[] AMINOS_PER_CODON = { 
            "F", "F", "L", "L", "S", "S",
            "S", "S", "Y", "Y", "C", "C", "W", "L", "L", "L", "L", "P", "P",
            "P", "P", "H", "H", "Q", "Q", "R", "R", "R", "R", "I", "I", "I",
            "M", "T", "T", "T", "T", "N", "N", "K", "K", "S", "S", "R", "R",
            "V", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "D", "E", "E", "G",
            "G", "G", "G", };

    private static  string[] AMINO_ABBREVIATIONS = {
            "F", "L", "I", "M", "V",
            "S", "P", "T", "A", "Y", "H", "Q", "N", "K", "D", "E", "C", "W",
            "R", "G" };

    private static string[] FULL_NAMES = { 
            "phenylalanine", "leucine",
            "isoleucine", "methionine", "valine", "serine", "proline",
            "threonine", "alanine", "tyrosine", "histidine", "glutamine",
            "asparagine", "lysine", "aspartic acid", "glutamic acid",
            "cysteine", "tryptophan", "arginine", "glycine" };

  static void Main()
  {
    //then input is DNA
    string dna = "TTCGAATCCGTATTGCTTTGGTTGGTTGAGAGAGCGACCTACATTGCTAGTCAGAATAGGTGATTCACACAAAGCTTAGCACCTGGGCAGCACCCCGTGATGTAAACCTATGGGAACTAAGGGAGTCCTGCGGTTTTAGCCAGCAAGCGAGCCGGCAGGAACACTCATACCATCGGACGCGTTTGACGCCTCCCCGGAAAGGAAGTATTTGAGCCTCATTATTACGTATTGCCCGTTAGTCGACAAATCAAGCCCTCGTACGCAGCTTATTCGTACGACGTGGAGGCGTTCCCACGGGCCTAACACGATTGGAACACCACCATAGTAGTGTGGTTCAAATACCTCCTTTGGAGATCTAGAGCTTCACTCTGATTCTAGAGGCAACTTTACAATCGCTCTACGAAATTGTATGGACATCATCAACCGGATATTCTGGGGCGGTAGAATTTCTTTTGTTCGAATCGCTCTAGGCCAGGATCAAATTAATTGAATTGCGGACTCAAGGATCGCGATAGCCGACACATCGGACGCTGTAGAAAGCCAGTCTCTGGATTTAATCCACCCTCTATGTTTGACAAAGCACTAAAACGGGATAGTTTCGGGTGGTATAAGTTTCCCAAGACGATTGCATCGCAATTCATCAACAACCATGAACTTACTGTTTTAGTACTTCCACACACCTTGTTAAATTACGCCTTTACTTCATGTTGCGGTGTGTGTTAGATAGTGTGCAGCTACAAGTCTACCGCCATCGCAGCTCGGGATACCGGCAGATGAGATGGTCCTGAGCTCGTACCGGACTCAAACTTTTTCCTTTACTACCTAGGAATCGCCCATGCGAATTTGTCGGACACACACCATTACATTAACGTCACAACAGCTACTGTTAGAATTTTGCTCTTGCAAATCCTGGAAAGAGTTAAAAAAACTCTTCCGCGCGCCAATAGGGTAAATAATAGATAGCCAGACGGCTGTAAGAGGTGATGACATTTGCAACAATCATGCTGTCGCATCTTCCGCAAGTTCATGTCGCGCCTAGGCAATGGATCTGCGAATGGGGGCCACGGGGTATGAACTACGGAATTCTAAGAAAGTTGCCATCCAGAGTTAAGGGTTTGAGGCTAGTTGCATCGCTGGTAACGAACTACCTCATTACTTGGACGCGCAGTGTGACTTCACTCCTGTATAGCGATGATGCCAAGCAGGAATTAGCAAATCTGAAGAGCGTTTCCAAACTGGCCACTTGGACTGACACCTATCGCGGGGGATTTCAGCGCGTGTCGCTCTCACATGAGAGCTGCCGTCAGGAGCGGTAGAGTTTAGAGAGGAATGCGACAAACTCCCTATTCACCTCTCTGGTGATGTAAGGATATTTACGCTTAGTTCTATGCCAGGCTTAGGGCCTCTCGGAACTTTGGTGAGTCCTTATTAATTGATGCTACCTCTCCCTTACCTTCGCCCCAAGTCACGTAGAAGTACTCAATCCTGCTACATGATAATCAAATATTTCCAACGTTGGGAAATCGGTGACATCACATACTAGTTAAGAAACCACTGTCAGTGAACTTATATCCGGGGGAGAAAATCTACTAACTTACATACGCTGTGCGAGCAGTTTTCATTATAAGAAAATATACTCCCGAGGTACCGCATCAAGCACGACATTCCCGGAGAGCATAACATTTCGGTGCACCTGCTTTTGTGCGCTTGCTTGCGGTTATTTATAAACTACGCACAAGGCGCAAACCGCAGTGCGCATGTTTTCTCCGCCTGGCTAGAACTCGACATTCTCGTCAACGCCAATCTATGTGAGAGGATTTAGACCTCTGTGAAAACGAGTCCCTCTATAGAATAAATACCCAGATGCCAATGGGGGTTCTATCCGATGGCAGTGCATGGAGTGGTGGCTCCAGATTAAGGATGAGGAGAGGTAAAGATAACAGTTCGGTCGCCACGACGCGTTGCCAATCGAAATATCAGTACTAAAAGGCCCACCGCTCCGCTTTAGTCCGACTTTACATCCTGTGGAAATTGTCGAACGGAGGCTACATCGGGCTATATGAGTGTGAAAACCTATACTTCTCGCGTCGTTACTCAGTGCCGGTCTCCTGTTTCCCCCAGTCTTACGTACCCTTATTGATATTTGCTTCACGTTGAAACGTCCTAACGCAGCGTAAAGAGGTGTTTGAACCTCATTACTATAAAATCGCGATCGAAGGTAGACTACATACGCAAACGCCGAAACCCTCAGTTGGCCTTGTTGCAAGTATGGAACGTTGTAAAATTTTTCCTAGACGTTGAGCTATCGGTACAAGGTCGTTAGCGTCCTTACCCTTCACTTATATGCCCGACAAAACGCGGGTCCTAGTGCAGTGGTGGGAGCTTGGAATCCCGCAATACAAGGACAACCTGTATCTCGTTCGGCGTTCCGCGATCACTCGATCCCGAACCACTCCAAGCCTGGTTGATCAGCAAAAGCGGAAGGATGGATAAAGGGCTACTGGTTAATGGATGTAAACTTCCAATGATGAAATCCTGGAAACGAGGGATCGGGTTACGGTGGCGAACGGGGTACGGCAACGTGGCTATCTAGAGCCCGACGTTACGACTCATGTACATGCTGCTACGTGGTTGAAGCTGACGTTCAGATGAAGCAGTACTGAGTCCTAGGGCTTACTACTACTCCAATAGGTCTGGCCGGCCAGATACAAAAGTTCGTGGCGGCTCACCCCCTTTCTGGCGGGTGTAGCTTGCTGACCGGTTTGCTCGATAACACAGGCTAGCGAATAGTAATGAGGTTCGAAAACCTCTTTCCAACGACTGAAAGGGTCTACACGAACTATCTACATTTCCCCGCCCATGTCCTTCCGTCTGGTTGCTTCTGGAGATCCTTTCGCATTATACCGCAGCGTAGTGGCTCTGGCATATATGAAAAAATCCTTCTGTGGGTATTTGTGCCATCACTTATTGTTCGTACCGATATGGGATTACAAGTGCGATGTGATAATAAGCGAAGAAGCCAACATGTTACACTGTTCATGCGCTCCGGGTAATGTGCGGGCACCATGCTCAGTTCCCGCTCGCAGTTGTCACTGTCCCTGTTTCGGCACCATAATCAACATTTCCACGGCCACGCTGGTGAATAACCGAGGATACCGAAGTACAGCAAGAATGAGAGCGGGACTCCTCCATCTGCTTGTAATACGCCTTCAAGATAGTCCATAAAACGGTCGGGGTCTTGTTTCGGACTAGCCGCTTTGAAACGGTGCATAGTTGTGTCAAGTGTGGACATTGGCTTTCTATCCTCGTCAGCGATCCTCGGAAAGACTCGGGCAGTCGCCCCGAATCGTAATTAGGTAGTAGTGCGGCTCAAAAACTTCCTTCGACCTAACCGCTATAATGTTCGTAGATATAAATTTCGTTTCAGTATTAACAGGCGCACCGTATATATACGGAATGGTGTCGCCCCATTAGCTGCTCGCCAATATTTATCTAAGACCGCGCGCGTCTAGCGCCTTTAGTAGTTGCACCCGAGTATAGTAATGGGGTTCGAAGACTTCCTTCGCAAGGCTGCCATACTGTATCACAAGTACTGACGGAGCCCCGGAGGAGTGCAGGATACGGCAAAGGAGACCATTACCGGGGCATGAGTCCAAGTTAGCCCGTTAGGTGAAGGACGCTGATACAATAGTGAATCCGTTACTGAAAGGTTTAGAAGACCGGGGGGCTCGCACTAGGTCCAAATATTATGAACCCTACTCCTGCAACTGAATTGGCCGTCCAGGCGATATTTAAAAGGGGTTACTAGCAGGTTCATCGGAGCCCGTACTCCTTCCGGGCATAGTCGTTCGACGGGTAGAAATTCATCCAGTCGTGCCGGATACCCCGAGAATACCCCTATTTTTTGATCCTTCACCATCATCGTCCGCGGACTCATCTAAGTACCTCAGACCGAAACTGTTATCGTAGCGAAGAGCGAACTCGAATGACATCGCTTGTCCAACAGGGAAAATATGTAAAGTATATGCAGATTATTATAGGAAGATCACAAACTCCATCGCGCCTAGGCCAAAGACTTGCCAGAACAACATCTCTTCCAGAGCAAGGAAGTGTTTGAACCTCACTATTATCGAGAGAAGTCCCATGAATTTATAATAGTGAGGCTCAAAAACTTCCTTCATCGTCGGGCGCTGGGGCGAGCTAGGCTTCCCTAGCCGTCATTACTGTACCCACGCCAAATATTATCGAGTATGACTACGAAGCCTTCACAAGGGGCTGCAGTAACAGACTAACTCACGCACACCGCAACTACTATCCTAAATTGAGTAAGAAAACCCTCGACTATAGCCCTTGAATTAAATTCGCTATTTAAGGAAGACCGCGCTTCCGCTCGCCCGCGTATAGTTTACCAGTCCCAAGAAACATGTGTGGCCAGCCTACCTGAAGAGCTGTGTAAAGATAGATTCTGACATCCTCAAAAAGAAGTTTTCGAGCCGCACTACTACGCACGGAGCTCCGTTATTCAAGGCATGTCGAAGTACAGCGTGGTGGCCTCTCCTGTTCTCCACCCCAGCTAAACCCACCTTGTTCGAATTCGCGCAACTGTATATGACATGAACACTTACAGGGGTTAGAAGTTACTGCAACCAAGATAGAGCTCGTCGAAGTAATAGTGCGGTTCAAAAACTTCCTTCAATTGGTCTCATCACTTAAATTTAAGAGCTATTGTGAGTACAGGTACGGATGCGGCTTCAGTGGATCTTCAGCATTCATTCCTTGTAGTAATGGGGTTCGAAGACTTCCTTGCCAGGGTACCAAACAAGTCTTGCGCATCCTCCTCCCTAAGGAGGTATTTGAACCCCACTATTACCCACGATAGAACATGCAGGGTTTGATAGTGGAACACCTTTTAGAATCTGGGGATAAATTCCCAGGACTAATGTATGGCTGTAGTAATGAGGTTCAAAAACCTCCTTTTCAGGTGGATCGCAGGCCGTGCTGCCTCACAAGCTGGGACGCCGTCCACGGTATAGCCGGCGTCGGCAGTTACTGTGAAATAGCGGAAACTCGATCCCAATATATCATCTTACGTTTGGCGCCCAATAGTCGCCCAGTACCCGTTGACAGTTCTTTAACTCGGCTTAGAACTACTAGACAGGTTCAACCGAACCTTGCCCTAGTTCCCACTCCCGTAATTCATTTGGGTTTGCATCTAGAATACTGGAGGGTGCATAGACGAAACGTGTACGTCGGAGAAAACGTAAGAAAATGACCTAGACTCATAGTAGTGAGGTTCGAAGACTTCCTTTCAGTGAAATCGATCCACCACTCGCCGCGAAGAGATAATAGCATAGAGCACAAGTGCGCGAGTAGAGAAAAAGGCTATCCCAACCGGGCACGTCCTTCGTGTTTGGCGTTTACATACGGCACCCCGTTTCTGCACGTTAACCGTCTAGTATCCAACGGTGGATGGCGGACGCTAGACTATAGATATGAGATATCGAGACCTGGAGCTGGGTGTGGCTGCAGCCCGGGTCATTGCGGGCTGTGAATTCAAGGGCATGTAAACAAGCGTATATCGAACAGTGGATGGGCACCTGCAATACTCACGGTAGAGTTAGCTCACAGGATTCACGTTGAGGACTATGAGTCCCTCTTCGCTAGCAGTCTGGGGGGATATGGAGTTTAATAGCTTGACGTAGTAATGGGGCTCAAACACCTCTTTGTGTGAGCACAGCTACTTGCATTAAGAGATTCTAAACAGCGATCATCTCGGCTATTTCGGGCCAGCCTTTTCGGCAGGATGTTATGTAGCATTTCTGGAAGCTTCCCCCTCGAATCTACTAGTGGTGAGAAGATGCCCCACCGATATTACTCTTTAATCTTGAGAAACCTAAAACCGATCTGACCTCAGACGGGCGGCTCCCACCCGAGGATAAACTCGTCAATAATAATGTGGCTCGAACACTTCTTTTCTCACTAGGCTTTTACGACACGCCACATGTATTTAAGCATCTACCTAACTTGTGTCTGCTGATATACAGCGCATTCTACGCCCAACCTACCAATTACTTCAACGTAGTGCGTGGCTAAAATTCAGGGGAGCTTCATCTCTGTCTTAATTTGAAGGTTCTTCCGGGGCGTTTGGGAATCTTCGTGCCTTTTGCGAGGTTAAGGTATCAAAGAAGTTTTCGAACCACATTATTACCGCCTTAAGCACCGGCGCATCCTGCTCGTGACAACTCTACCCTGCCCTGATAAAGGCACTGAACGTTCCAGAGAGTGCATCATTGACACGCGAGCAGGCCACAGTAGCCACAAGACGTATGGGTGATTATAGAATTGGTGGAGGTGTTGTTAACGATCAGGAGGACATTAGTGGGAGTTAGGAAAGACCCTATGTTCTCTCTATCGCGGACTTGTAACTTGACAAGCAAAAGGGTAAGAGAGCTGCACACCGAAGCAGGCCCTTCCTATACCTGTTTTTCCTACGCGTAGAGAGGAATCCAGAAAGGTGATAATTGGCATTCGATGAAAAAACAGTGTGCCACTGACTTAGTTCTATATGTGAAGAGCCTGTTAGCACGTGACGGCGGCCTTGGTATAGAGCCCTTAATGGTCTCCATCGCGTAGTAATGGGGCTCGAAAACCTCCTTACTTGGGATTGCGTGGCCTCCTTGTGAGTCATACACAAGGCTTAGGGCTATGGGGCGATACACTCCTTTTCGCGGCGCATGGGGCGGTGATGCCTACATAGTAGTAGTGACTGCCTTTCTGGGGGGCTATTTGTGGATGACCAACACCTGACCAGCGATGCAATCGCTAGGGGAGGTACACCTCTCATATGTTACAACAATCACCGAATTGTGTTTCGAATTCGAATCAAGTTTGCGGTGTCGACCAGATCTGGTCTTGCTGCCATACCGGGTTCGCCGCCTCCGGTGGATAGAACTGCATCTTAAGACATCTGGACCCAGCGGTAAGTAGCGGGAAGAGTTTAGAGTCATTCGTACAACTACAGGCTAAGGGCTTACTGGGGAGTTGTTGTAGGGCATAAAGATCGCCCCATGACTTTTCGTACTTTCCCCGATAGTTCACTCGCAGCGAGCTGCGGCTGGGCTTCGCCACACGAGTACGGGCAACATTTATCTCCTCTAATCACTGGGCACCGCGCGAGGAAATAGAAAACCCTAATCAGTGCTCATGGGCGCATCTATTGGTCTCCGCATGCACGATGCCGCGGAGTGCTTAGTTGTCCCTGCATAATCTTCGTAGATGTATAAGAGATTACCTATTTATTCGGTTTCGGTTCTAGACGTACCTTGCCGCATGAGTATAGGCTAATGAACTGAGTTGGCGCCAGAGGGAAAGGCATAATAATGCGGCTCGAATACTTCCTTAAGGAAGTATTCGAACCACATTACTAT";


    //The given peptide 
                    string givenPeptide = "KEVFEPHYY";
                    char[] givenPeptideArray = givenPeptide.ToCharArray() ;
                    string codon="";
                    string auxCodon="";
                    string convertedCodon = "";
                    string clean = "";
                    int pivot = 0;
                    int foundFlag = 0;
                    string cleanReverse = "";
                    int foundFlagReverse = 0;
                    string convertedCodonReverse = "";



    //so the idea I was working was to loop dna string until getting to 3*givenPeptide.Length 
    //because dna is red 3 by 3... 
    //then get givenPeptide.Length and compare each char of given peptide with encoded 
    //letter of scanned triplet 
    //so for example first givenpeptide is 'M' so I would search for 'ATG'
    //then, if found increment a counter and then search for next 'GCC' etc...
    //however When testing with longer string I do not get complete result
    //I have


                    for (int pos = 0; pos < dna.Length - (3*givenPeptide.Length)   ; pos++) {
                        pivot = pos;
                        for (int codonPos = 0; codonPos < givenPeptide.Length; codonPos++)
                        {
                            codon = dna.Substring(pivot, 3);
                            auxCodon = givenPeptideArray[codonPos].ToString();
                            convertedCodon = codonToAminoAcid(codon);
                            convertedCodonReverse = codonToAminoAcid(DNAComplement(codon));
                            if (auxCodon.Equals(convertedCodon) )
                            {
                                foundFlag++;
                                clean += codon;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                foundFlag = 0;
                                clean = "";
                            }
                            if (foundFlag == givenPeptide.Length)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(clean);
                                foundFlag = 0;
                                clean = "";
                            }
                            //reverse
                            if (auxCodon.Equals(convertedCodonReverse))
                            {
                                foundFlagReverse++;
                                cleanReverse += codon;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                foundFlagReverse = 0;
                                cleanReverse = "";
                            }
                            if (foundFlagReverse == givenPeptide.Length)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(cleanReverse);
                                foundFlagReverse = 0;
                                cleanReverse = "";
                            }
                            pivot+=3;
                        }
                    }
    }//end main

    public static string DNAComplement(string dna)
            {
                char[] array = dna.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    char let = array[i];
                    if      (let == 'A') array[i] = 'T';
                    else if (let == 'T') array[i] = 'A';
                    else if (let == 'C') array[i] = 'G';
                    else if (let == 'G') array[i] = 'C';
                }

                Array.Reverse(array);
                return new string(array);
            }


    public static string codonToAminoAcid(String codon)
            {

                for (int k = 0; k < CODONS.Length ; k++)
                {
                    if (CODONS[k].Equals (codon))
                    {
                        return AMINOS_PER_CODON[k];
                    }
                }

                // never reach here with valid codon
                return "X";
            }

}//end class
```

I should get

```
AAGGAAGTATTTGAGCCTCATTATTAC
AAAGAGGTGTTTGAACCTCATTACTAT
AAGGAGGTATTTGAACCCCACTATTAC
AAAGAAGTTTTCGAACCACATTATTAC
AAGGAAGTGTTTGAACCTCACTATTAT
AAAGAAGTTTTCGAGCCGCACTACTAC
AAGGAAGTATTCGAACCACATTACTAT
ATAATAATGCGGCTCGAATACTTCCTT
GTAGTAATGGGGCTCGAAAACCTCCTT
GTAGTAATGAGGTTCAAAAACCTCCTT
GTAGTAATGGGGTTCGAAGACTTCCTT
ATAATAGTGAGGCTCAAAAACTTCCTT
ATAGTAATGGGGTTCGAAGACTTCCTT
GTAGTAGTGCGGCTCAAAAACTTCCTT
ATAGTAATGAGGTTCGAAAACCTCTTT
ATAATAATGTGGCTCGAACACTTCTTT
GTAGTAATGGGGCTCAAACACCTCTTT
ATAGTAGTGAGGTTCGAAGACTTCCTT
GTAATAGTGCGGTTCAAAAACTTCCTT
ATAGTAGTGTGGTTCAAATACCTCCTT
```

However I am only getting:

```
AAGGAAGTATTTGAGCCTCATTATTAC
AAAGAGGTGTTTGAACCTCATTACTAT
AAGGAAGTGTTTGAACCTCACTATTAT
AAAGAAGTTTTCGAGCCGCACTACTAC
AAGGAGGTATTTGAACCCCACTATTAC
AAAGAAGTTTTCGAACCACATTATTAC
```

I was thinking on problem and It seems the problem is I am not looping all string each time...

Comment: Please share the code you're using to produce the output

Comment: You just put the code sun into arrays. Interesting. I bet it's a logical problem in your code.

Comment: @Akku the issue starts at for loop `for (int pos = 0; pos < dna.Length - (3*givenPeptide.Length)   ; pos++) { ...`  which is inside main

Comment: Whoa, hard to go through. OK, first things first. In your text, you say you're looking for ATGGCC, but in the code you have something strange that doesn't seem to make sense: KEVFEPHYY. Then, where you write 'never reach here with valid codon', you actually get there (just set a debug point there). Is that enough to get you on track? Otherwise I'll need to understand all that code, and I hate arrays.

Comment: The best idea have is to put that problem in my code. For that, I'd like to know: 1) Do I always have to start at the beginning of the DNA, or if I need to wait for a start-codon? 2) Do I always have to read three nuleobases at a time and translate them into an aminoacid, or can I step over, say, the first two, and then begin creating acids?

Comment: well, actually I forgot to tell the DNA string on code is a lot larger than example I first wrote, so KEVFEPHYY is other sequence of aminoacids, and also I have checked 'never reach here with valid codon' and it works (supposing correct input). For question one, the answer is no, you can start at first, second,...position of dna string, for question two, answer is yes, you always read 3 nucleobases at a time...

Comment: I copy pasted your code into Visual Studio, executed it, and reached the point where it shouldn't go. :-/

Comment: Are you sure, I created empty project and add this code, and got told Output...

Comment: I also got the told output. Did you ever use a debugger? If you click in the left free coluoums beside the line number in Visual Studio, a red dot appears. When you then execute the program, the execution halts at this point, so you can inspect what happens. Please try it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7vor8w540ne9b8/Screenshot%202013-11-27%2008.38.30.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is two-fold.  Your outer for loop doesn't go far enough to catch the very end of the dna string.  Secondly, it appears that reversing individual codons doesn't work and that you have to take the entire (givenPeptideLength * 3) character string before getting the complement.  The following changes output the strings you put in your example so I'm hopeful that it does what you want.  It has the benefit of being much more concise as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace DNA
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string[] CODONS = { 
                "TTT", "TTC", "TTA", "TTG", "TCT",
                "TCC", "TCA", "TCG", "TAT", "TAC", "TGT", "TGC", "TGG", "CTT",
                "CTC", "CTA", "CTG", "CCT", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG", "CAT", "CAC",
                "CAA", "CAG", "CGT", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "ATT", "ATC", "ATA",
                "ATG", "ACT", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG", "AAT", "AAC", "AAA", "AAG",
                "AGT", "AGC", "AGA", "AGG", "GTT", "GTC", "GTA", "GTG", "GCT",
                "GCC", "GCA", "GCG", "GAT", "GAC", "GAA", "GAG", "GGT", "GGC",
                "GGA", "GGG", };

        private static string[] AMINOS_PER_CODON = { 
            "F", "F", "L", "L", "S", "S",
            "S", "S", "Y", "Y", "C", "C", "W", "L", "L", "L", "L", "P", "P",
            "P", "P", "H", "H", "Q", "Q", "R", "R", "R", "R", "I", "I", "I",
            "M", "T", "T", "T", "T", "N", "N", "K", "K", "S", "S", "R", "R",
            "V", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "D", "E", "E", "G",
            "G", "G", "G", };

        private static string[] AMINO_ABBREVIATIONS = {
            "F", "L", "I", "M", "V",
            "S", "P", "T", "A", "Y", "H", "Q", "N", "K", "D", "E", "C", "W",
            "R", "G" };

        private static string[] FULL_NAMES = { 
            "phenylalanine", "leucine",
            "isoleucine", "methionine", "valine", "serine", "proline",
            "threonine", "alanine", "tyrosine", "histidine", "glutamine",
            "asparagine", "lysine", "aspartic acid", "glutamic acid",
            "cysteine", "tryptophan", "arginine", "glycine" };

        public static string DNAComplement(string dna)
        {
            char[] array = dna.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                char let = array[i];
                if (let == 'A') array[i] = 'T';
                else if (let == 'T') array[i] = 'A';
                else if (let == 'C') array[i] = 'G';
                else if (let == 'G') array[i] = 'C';
            }

            Array.Reverse(array);
            return new string(array);
        }

        public static string StringToAminoAcid(String input)
        {
            string result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 3)
            {
                result += codonToAminoAcid(input.Substring(i, 3));
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static string codonToAminoAcid(String codon)
        {

            for (int k = 0; k < CODONS.Length; k++)
            {
                if (CODONS[k].Equals(codon))
                {
                    return AMINOS_PER_CODON[k];
                }
            }

            // never reach here with valid codon
            return "X";
        }


        static void Main()
        {
            //then input is DNA
            string dna = "TTCGAATCCGTATTGCTTTGGTTGGTTGAGAGAGCGACCTACATTGCTAGTCAGAATAGGTGATTCACACAAAGCTTAGCACCTGGGCAGCACCCCGTGATGTAAACCTATGGGAACTAAGGGAGTCCTGCGGTTTTAGCCAGCAAGCGAGCCGGCAGGAACACTCATACCATCGGACGCGTTTGACGCCTCCCCGGAAAGGAAGTATTTGAGCCTCATTATTACGTATTGCCCGTTAGTCGACAAATCAAGCCCTCGTACGCAGCTTATTCGTACGACGTGGAGGCGTTCCCACGGGCCTAACACGATTGGAACACCACCATAGTAGTGTGGTTCAAATACCTCCTTTGGAGATCTAGAGCTTCACTCTGATTCTAGAGGCAACTTTACAATCGCTCTACGAAATTGTATGGACATCATCAACCGGATATTCTGGGGCGGTAGAATTTCTTTTGTTCGAATCGCTCTAGGCCAGGATCAAATTAATTGAATTGCGGACTCAAGGATCGCGATAGCCGACACATCGGACGCTGTAGAAAGCCAGTCTCTGGATTTAATCCACCCTCTATGTTTGACAAAGCACTAAAACGGGATAGTTTCGGGTGGTATAAGTTTCCCAAGACGATTGCATCGCAATTCATCAACAACCATGAACTTACTGTTTTAGTACTTCCACACACCTTGTTAAATTACGCCTTTACTTCATGTTGCGGTGTGTGTTAGATAGTGTGCAGCTACAAGTCTACCGCCATCGCAGCTCGGGATACCGGCAGATGAGATGGTCCTGAGCTCGTACCGGACTCAAACTTTTTCCTTTACTACCTAGGAATCGCCCATGCGAATTTGTCGGACACACACCATTACATTAACGTCACAACAGCTACTGTTAGAATTTTGCTCTTGCAAATCCTGGAAAGAGTTAAAAAAACTCTTCCGCGCGCCAATAGGGTAAATAATAGATAGCCAGACGGCTGTAAGAGGTGATGACATTTGCAACAATCATGCTGTCGCATCTTCCGCAAGTTCATGTCGCGCCTAGGCAATGGATCTGCGAATGGGGGCCACGGGGTATGAACTACGGAATTCTAAGAAAGTTGCCATCCAGAGTTAAGGGTTTGAGGCTAGTTGCATCGCTGGTAACGAACTACCTCATTACTTGGACGCGCAGTGTGACTTCACTCCTGTATAGCGATGATGCCAAGCAGGAATTAGCAAATCTGAAGAGCGTTTCCAAACTGGCCACTTGGACTGACACCTATCGCGGGGGATTTCAGCGCGTGTCGCTCTCACATGAGAGCTGCCGTCAGGAGCGGTAGAGTTTAGAGAGGAATGCGACAAACTCCCTATTCACCTCTCTGGTGATGTAAGGATATTTACGCTTAGTTCTATGCCAGGCTTAGGGCCTCTCGGAACTTTGGTGAGTCCTTATTAATTGATGCTACCTCTCCCTTACCTTCGCCCCAAGTCACGTAGAAGTACTCAATCCTGCTACATGATAATCAAATATTTCCAACGTTGGGAAATCGGTGACATCACATACTAGTTAAGAAACCACTGTCAGTGAACTTATATCCGGGGGAGAAAATCTACTAACTTACATACGCTGTGCGAGCAGTTTTCATTATAAGAAAATATACTCCCGAGGTACCGCATCAAGCACGACATTCCCGGAGAGCATAACATTTCGGTGCACCTGCTTTTGTGCGCTTGCTTGCGGTTATTTATAAACTACGCACAAGGCGCAAACCGCAGTGCGCATGTTTTCTCCGCCTGGCTAGAACTCGACATTCTCGTCAACGCCAATCTATGTGAGAGGATTTAGACCTCTGTGAAAACGAGTCCCTCTATAGAATAAATACCCAGATGCCAATGGGGGTTCTATCCGATGGCAGTGCATGGAGTGGTGGCTCCAGATTAAGGATGAGGAGAGGTAAAGATAACAGTTCGGTCGCCACGACGCGTTGCCAATCGAAATATCAGTACTAAAAGGCCCACCGCTCCGCTTTAGTCCGACTTTACATCCTGTGGAAATTGTCGAACGGAGGCTACATCGGGCTATATGAGTGTGAAAACCTATACTTCTCGCGTCGTTACTCAGTGCCGGTCTCCTGTTTCCCCCAGTCTTACGTACCCTTATTGATATTTGCTTCACGTTGAAACGTCCTAACGCAGCGTAAAGAGGTGTTTGAACCTCATTACTATAAAATCGCGATCGAAGGTAGACTACATACGCAAACGCCGAAACCCTCAGTTGGCCTTGTTGCAAGTATGGAACGTTGTAAAATTTTTCCTAGACGTTGAGCTATCGGTACAAGGTCGTTAGCGTCCTTACCCTTCACTTATATGCCCGACAAAACGCGGGTCCTAGTGCAGTGGTGGGAGCTTGGAATCCCGCAATACAAGGACAACCTGTATCTCGTTCGGCGTTCCGCGATCACTCGATCCCGAACCACTCCAAGCCTGGTTGATCAGCAAAAGCGGAAGGATGGATAAAGGGCTACTGGTTAATGGATGTAAACTTCCAATGATGAAATCCTGGAAACGAGGGATCGGGTTACGGTGGCGAACGGGGTACGGCAACGTGGCTATCTAGAGCCCGACGTTACGACTCATGTACATGCTGCTACGTGGTTGAAGCTGACGTTCAGATGAAGCAGTACTGAGTCCTAGGGCTTACTACTACTCCAATAGGTCTGGCCGGCCAGATACAAAAGTTCGTGGCGGCTCACCCCCTTTCTGGCGGGTGTAGCTTGCTGACCGGTTTGCTCGATAACACAGGCTAGCGAATAGTAATGAGGTTCGAAAACCTCTTTCCAACGACTGAAAGGGTCTACACGAACTATCTACATTTCCCCGCCCATGTCCTTCCGTCTGGTTGCTTCTGGAGATCCTTTCGCATTATACCGCAGCGTAGTGGCTCTGGCATATATGAAAAAATCCTTCTGTGGGTATTTGTGCCATCACTTATTGTTCGTACCGATATGGGATTACAAGTGCGATGTGATAATAAGCGAAGAAGCCAACATGTTACACTGTTCATGCGCTCCGGGTAATGTGCGGGCACCATGCTCAGTTCCCGCTCGCAGTTGTCACTGTCCCTGTTTCGGCACCATAATCAACATTTCCACGGCCACGCTGGTGAATAACCGAGGATACCGAAGTACAGCAAGAATGAGAGCGGGACTCCTCCATCTGCTTGTAATACGCCTTCAAGATAGTCCATAAAACGGTCGGGGTCTTGTTTCGGACTAGCCGCTTTGAAACGGTGCATAGTTGTGTCAAGTGTGGACATTGGCTTTCTATCCTCGTCAGCGATCCTCGGAAAGACTCGGGCAGTCGCCCCGAATCGTAATTAGGTAGTAGTGCGGCTCAAAAACTTCCTTCGACCTAACCGCTATAATGTTCGTAGATATAAATTTCGTTTCAGTATTAACAGGCGCACCGTATATATACGGAATGGTGTCGCCCCATTAGCTGCTCGCCAATATTTATCTAAGACCGCGCGCGTCTAGCGCCTTTAGTAGTTGCACCCGAGTATAGTAATGGGGTTCGAAGACTTCCTTCGCAAGGCTGCCATACTGTATCACAAGTACTGACGGAGCCCCGGAGGAGTGCAGGATACGGCAAAGGAGACCATTACCGGGGCATGAGTCCAAGTTAGCCCGTTAGGTGAAGGACGCTGATACAATAGTGAATCCGTTACTGAAAGGTTTAGAAGACCGGGGGGCTCGCACTAGGTCCAAATATTATGAACCCTACTCCTGCAACTGAATTGGCCGTCCAGGCGATATTTAAAAGGGGTTACTAGCAGGTTCATCGGAGCCCGTACTCCTTCCGGGCATAGTCGTTCGACGGGTAGAAATTCATCCAGTCGTGCCGGATACCCCGAGAATACCCCTATTTTTTGATCCTTCACCATCATCGTCCGCGGACTCATCTAAGTACCTCAGACCGAAACTGTTATCGTAGCGAAGAGCGAACTCGAATGACATCGCTTGTCCAACAGGGAAAATATGTAAAGTATATGCAGATTATTATAGGAAGATCACAAACTCCATCGCGCCTAGGCCAAAGACTTGCCAGAACAACATCTCTTCCAGAGCAAGGAAGTGTTTGAACCTCACTATTATCGAGAGAAGTCCCATGAATTTATAATAGTGAGGCTCAAAAACTTCCTTCATCGTCGGGCGCTGGGGCGAGCTAGGCTTCCCTAGCCGTCATTACTGTACCCACGCCAAATATTATCGAGTATGACTACGAAGCCTTCACAAGGGGCTGCAGTAACAGACTAACTCACGCACACCGCAACTACTATCCTAAATTGAGTAAGAAAACCCTCGACTATAGCCCTTGAATTAAATTCGCTATTTAAGGAAGACCGCGCTTCCGCTCGCCCGCGTATAGTTTACCAGTCCCAAGAAACATGTGTGGCCAGCCTACCTGAAGAGCTGTGTAAAGATAGATTCTGACATCCTCAAAAAGAAGTTTTCGAGCCGCACTACTACGCACGGAGCTCCGTTATTCAAGGCATGTCGAAGTACAGCGTGGTGGCCTCTCCTGTTCTCCACCCCAGCTAAACCCACCTTGTTCGAATTCGCGCAACTGTATATGACATGAACACTTACAGGGGTTAGAAGTTACTGCAACCAAGATAGAGCTCGTCGAAGTAATAGTGCGGTTCAAAAACTTCCTTCAATTGGTCTCATCACTTAAATTTAAGAGCTATTGTGAGTACAGGTACGGATGCGGCTTCAGTGGATCTTCAGCATTCATTCCTTGTAGTAATGGGGTTCGAAGACTTCCTTGCCAGGGTACCAAACAAGTCTTGCGCATCCTCCTCCCTAAGGAGGTATTTGAACCCCACTATTACCCACGATAGAACATGCAGGGTTTGATAGTGGAACACCTTTTAGAATCTGGGGATAAATTCCCAGGACTAATGTATGGCTGTAGTAATGAGGTTCAAAAACCTCCTTTTCAGGTGGATCGCAGGCCGTGCTGCCTCACAAGCTGGGACGCCGTCCACGGTATAGCCGGCGTCGGCAGTTACTGTGAAATAGCGGAAACTCGATCCCAATATATCATCTTACGTTTGGCGCCCAATAGTCGCCCAGTACCCGTTGACAGTTCTTTAACTCGGCTTAGAACTACTAGACAGGTTCAACCGAACCTTGCCCTAGTTCCCACTCCCGTAATTCATTTGGGTTTGCATCTAGAATACTGGAGGGTGCATAGACGAAACGTGTACGTCGGAGAAAACGTAAGAAAATGACCTAGACTCATAGTAGTGAGGTTCGAAGACTTCCTTTCAGTGAAATCGATCCACCACTCGCCGCGAAGAGATAATAGCATAGAGCACAAGTGCGCGAGTAGAGAAAAAGGCTATCCCAACCGGGCACGTCCTTCGTGTTTGGCGTTTACATACGGCACCCCGTTTCTGCACGTTAACCGTCTAGTATCCAACGGTGGATGGCGGACGCTAGACTATAGATATGAGATATCGAGACCTGGAGCTGGGTGTGGCTGCAGCCCGGGTCATTGCGGGCTGTGAATTCAAGGGCATGTAAACAAGCGTATATCGAACAGTGGATGGGCACCTGCAATACTCACGGTAGAGTTAGCTCACAGGATTCACGTTGAGGACTATGAGTCCCTCTTCGCTAGCAGTCTGGGGGGATATGGAGTTTAATAGCTTGACGTAGTAATGGGGCTCAAACACCTCTTTGTGTGAGCACAGCTACTTGCATTAAGAGATTCTAAACAGCGATCATCTCGGCTATTTCGGGCCAGCCTTTTCGGCAGGATGTTATGTAGCATTTCTGGAAGCTTCCCCCTCGAATCTACTAGTGGTGAGAAGATGCCCCACCGATATTACTCTTTAATCTTGAGAAACCTAAAACCGATCTGACCTCAGACGGGCGGCTCCCACCCGAGGATAAACTCGTCAATAATAATGTGGCTCGAACACTTCTTTTCTCACTAGGCTTTTACGACACGCCACATGTATTTAAGCATCTACCTAACTTGTGTCTGCTGATATACAGCGCATTCTACGCCCAACCTACCAATTACTTCAACGTAGTGCGTGGCTAAAATTCAGGGGAGCTTCATCTCTGTCTTAATTTGAAGGTTCTTCCGGGGCGTTTGGGAATCTTCGTGCCTTTTGCGAGGTTAAGGTATCAAAGAAGTTTTCGAACCACATTATTACCGCCTTAAGCACCGGCGCATCCTGCTCGTGACAACTCTACCCTGCCCTGATAAAGGCACTGAACGTTCCAGAGAGTGCATCATTGACACGCGAGCAGGCCACAGTAGCCACAAGACGTATGGGTGATTATAGAATTGGTGGAGGTGTTGTTAACGATCAGGAGGACATTAGTGGGAGTTAGGAAAGACCCTATGTTCTCTCTATCGCGGACTTGTAACTTGACAAGCAAAAGGGTAAGAGAGCTGCACACCGAAGCAGGCCCTTCCTATACCTGTTTTTCCTACGCGTAGAGAGGAATCCAGAAAGGTGATAATTGGCATTCGATGAAAAAACAGTGTGCCACTGACTTAGTTCTATATGTGAAGAGCCTGTTAGCACGTGACGGCGGCCTTGGTATAGAGCCCTTAATGGTCTCCATCGCGTAGTAATGGGGCTCGAAAACCTCCTTACTTGGGATTGCGTGGCCTCCTTGTGAGTCATACACAAGGCTTAGGGCTATGGGGCGATACACTCCTTTTCGCGGCGCATGGGGCGGTGATGCCTACATAGTAGTAGTGACTGCCTTTCTGGGGGGCTATTTGTGGATGACCAACACCTGACCAGCGATGCAATCGCTAGGGGAGGTACACCTCTCATATGTTACAACAATCACCGAATTGTGTTTCGAATTCGAATCAAGTTTGCGGTGTCGACCAGATCTGGTCTTGCTGCCATACCGGGTTCGCCGCCTCCGGTGGATAGAACTGCATCTTAAGACATCTGGACCCAGCGGTAAGTAGCGGGAAGAGTTTAGAGTCATTCGTACAACTACAGGCTAAGGGCTTACTGGGGAGTTGTTGTAGGGCATAAAGATCGCCCCATGACTTTTCGTACTTTCCCCGATAGTTCACTCGCAGCGAGCTGCGGCTGGGCTTCGCCACACGAGTACGGGCAACATTTATCTCCTCTAATCACTGGGCACCGCGCGAGGAAATAGAAAACCCTAATCAGTGCTCATGGGCGCATCTATTGGTCTCCGCATGCACGATGCCGCGGAGTGCTTAGTTGTCCCTGCATAATCTTCGTAGATGTATAAGAGATTACCTATTTATTCGGTTTCGGTTCTAGACGTACCTTGCCGCATGAGTATAGGCTAATGAACTGAGTTGGCGCCAGAGGGAAAGGCATAATAATGCGGCTCGAATACTTCCTTAAGGAAGTATTCGAACCACATTACTAT";

            //The given peptide 
            string givenPeptide = "KEVFEPHYY";
            int resultCount = 0;
            int candidateLength = givenPeptide.Length * 3;
            string forward = "";
            string backward = "";

            for (int pos = 0; pos < dna.Length - candidateLength + 1; pos++)  // Added the "+ 1"
            {
                forward = dna.Substring(pos, candidateLength);
                backward = DNAComplement(forward);

                // Unremark to get a glimpse into what is happening...
                //Console.WriteLine("pos: {0}, forward: {1}, backward: {2}, forwardTranslation: {3}, backwardTranslation: {4}",
                //    pos, forward, backward, StringToAminoAcid(forward), StringToAminoAcid(backward));

                if (
                    (StringToAminoAcid(forward) == givenPeptide)
                    ||
                    (StringToAminoAcid(backward) == givenPeptide)
                  )
                {
                    resultCount++;
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Result {0,3} at position {1,6}... {2}", resultCount, pos, forward));
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }//end main
    }//end class
}
```

Comment: i wish some one will see this! I have peptide say MAW   i want code to get its all possible encodings ie AUBCAGUGG etc...i have found the codons for each of M,A and W now I want to find the different combinations of these codons that will  produce the peptide

Comment: I mean general solution for p1p2p3..pn peptide

Comment: @kobosh - You will have a much better chance if you post as a question rather than a comment, show what you have tried thus far, and provide sample input and expected output in your question.  I only became aware of your comment because I got an email notification because I answered this question.  Very few others will stumble upon your comment.