# Converting nucleotide sequence to amino acid sequence

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a script that used the location of a gene, and the strand information (complement, forward), to extract the nucleotide sequence. Once extracted, the script uses the translation table and the codon start position to convert the nucleotide sequence to an amino acid sequence and compares it to the original amino acid sequence. In theory, they should match, but I have yet to get a match.

As an example, I will use this E. *coli* genbank file: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AB011549 Starting on/near line 396 is the following:

```
CDS         complement(25341..26294)
/gene="repFIB"
/note="Replication protein RepFIB (P307 replicon);
similar to PIR accession number A32310"
/codon_start=1
/transl_table=11
/product="RepFIB"
/protein_id="BAA31780.2"
/db_xref="GI:4589743"
/translation="MTLTPNNNNTVQPVALMRLGVFVPTLKSLKNSKKNTLSRTDATEELTRLSLARAEGFDKVEITGPRLDMDNDFKTWVGIIHSFARHNVIGDKVELPFVEFAKLCGIPSSQSSRRLRERISPSLKRIAGTVISFSRTDEKHTREYITHLVQSAYYDTERDIVQLQADPRLFELYQFDRKVLLQLKAINALKRRESAQALYTFIESLPRDPAPVSLARLRARLNLKSPVFSQNQTVRRAMEQLREIGYLDYTEIQRGRTKLFCIHYRRPRLKAPNDESKENPLPPSPAEKVSPEMAEKLALLEKLGITLDDLEKLFKSR"
```

This tells me that the translation table is #11, the gene starts in position 25341 and ends at 26294, the gene comes from the complement strand, and the actual amino acid sequence is the last entry (e.g., /translation).

```
import Bio
import os
from Bio import GenBank
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import SeqFeature

genome_file = 'GenbankFiles_E_coli/AB011549.gb'

#complement strand
nAA = 'MTLTPNNNNTVQPVALMRLGVFVPTLKSLKNSKKNTLSRTDATEELTRLSLARAEGFDKVEITGPRLDMDNDFKTWVGIIHSFARHNVIGDKVELPFVEFAKLCGIPSSQSSRRLRERISPSLKRIAGTVISFSRTDEKHTREYITHLVQSAYYDTERDIVQLQADPRLFELYQFDRKVLLQLKAINALKRRESAQALYTFIESLPRDPAPVSLARLRARLNLKSPVFSQNQTVRRAMEQLREIGYLDYTEIQRGRTKLFCIHYRRPRLKAPNDESKENPLPPSPAEKVSPEMAEKLALLEKLGITLDDLEKLFKSR'

#Forward strand
NA = 'MLLALLSSTDNFCLSSTELSERLDVSRTYITRACDSLEKFGFIKRMESKEDRRSKNIYLTSDGNLYLQRTTRIYGRYLKKYGATLQMMKSKHLK'

gene_nucleotide = ''

def match(sequence, index):
    print('match')
    print(index, sequence)
    exit()

def get_aminoAcid(nucleotide_sequence, amino_sequence, start_position, stop_position, string=''):
    index = -2
    calls = [nucleotide_sequence[start_position+index:stop_position+index].translate(table=11), nucleotide_sequence[start_position+index:stop_position+index].complement().translate(table=11), nucleotide_sequence[start_position+index:stop_position+index].reverse_complement().translate(table=11)]

    while index < 3:
        print(index)
        stringT = str(nucleotide_sequence[start_position+index:stop_position+index].translate(table=11))
        stringC = str(nucleotide_sequence[start_position+index:stop_position+index].complement().translate(table=11))
        stringRC = str(nucleotide_sequence[start_position+index:stop_position+index].reverse_complement().translate(table=11))

        if stringT == amino_sequence:
            match(stringT, index)
        if stringC  == amino_sequence:
            match(stringC, index)
        if stringRC  == amino_sequence:
            match(stringRC, index)

        #uncomment to see actual translations
        #print('translate:', stringT, '\n')
        #print('complement:', stringC, '\n')
        #print('reverse_complement:', stringRC, '\n')

        index+=1

record = next(SeqIO.parse(genome_file, 'genbank'))
sequence = record.seq
start  = 25341 
stop = 26294 
get_aminoAcid(sequence, nAA, start, stop)

#This is from a forward strand
start  = 23512
stop = 23796 
get_aminoAcid(sequence, NA, start, stop)
```

Please note that my script looks at following: forward strand (*.translate(table=11)), complement strand (*.complement().translate(table=11)), and reverse complement (*.reverse_complement().translate(table=11)).

Even though the genbank file states that the gene starts in position 25341 and has an open reading frame in position 1 (e.g., codon_start=1), I checked all three translations starting in reading frames from -2, -1, 0 (this is the original start position), +1, +2...and I still cannot find a match for a complementary strand. However, this script does work for a forward nucleotide strand (see last few lines which uses information for a different coding sequence).

Here is my output:

```
/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Bio/Seq.py:2041: BiopythonWarning: Partial codon, len(sequence) not a multiple of three. Explicitly trim the sequence or add trailing N before translation. This may become an error in future. BiopythonWarning)
-2
-1
0
1
2
-2 #starting over using different CDS (forward)
-1
match
-1 MLLALLSSTDNFCLSSTELSERLDVSRTYITRACDSLEKFGFIKRMESKEDRRSKNIYLTSDGNLYLQRTTRIYGRYLKKYGATLQMMKSKHL
```

So, converting a forward strand nucleotide sequence into a matching amino acid sequence works, but the complement does not and I cannot figure out why (it is likely an error I made in Biopython). Can anybody provide some insight as to what I did incorrectly and how I can rectify it?

A *very* brief explanation as to how nucleotides are converted to amino acids: A codon/amino acid is made up of three nucleotides. Look at the amino acid chart here: [How to complete getting substrings of a genome encoding a given amino acid sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209067/how-to-complete-getting-substrings-of-a-genome-encoding-a-given-amino-acid-seque)
If my nucleotide sequence is GCG, starting at the center of the circle and make my way out to the edge, G (inner circle) C (middle circle) G (outer circle) corresponds to Alanine (A).

Comment: A common problem is converting 0-based (Python) indexing into 1-based (nucleotide) numbering.  What happens if you print out the reverse complement nucleotide sequence? Does it start with an ATG, as you'd expect, or does it start one off, like TG...?

Comment: ... actually in the specific case you show here, it's because the annotation is incorrect.  I don't know why, but the translation they say is there, is not; instead of an initiating ATG (CAT in reverse complement), there is a GAC (GTC in reverse complement) which encodes Val;  the rest of the sequence corresponds to the translation as given.

Comment: Thank you @iayork...I have only looked at 5 complement strands in the file but I have not been able to slice, convert, and translate into a match for any of them. Surely all the annotations cannot be wrong...I am still operating under the assumption that it is my script that is wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: The ones I looked at were clearly not completely wrong, they were nearly a perfect match, but different at a single point, e.g. the annotation says "M", the actual sequence was "L".  I don't think your script is wrong; try it on another annotated sequence and I bet it will work

Comment: @iayork Bacteria translate GTG as V when it occures within a gene, but as M when it occures as a start codon. See http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Utils/wprintgc.cgi#SG11

Comment: @heathobrien I thought I checked for alternate start codons, but I missed that somehow.  That's probably what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am slightly embarrassed to say that the issue was not my code, but rather my interpretation. A CDS feature (e.g. CDS complement(xx...xxxx)) may be from the complement strand, but there is no need for me to convert it (e.g., reverse_complement(), complement()) first. I simply translate it directly (e.g., translate(table=11)).

There may be some issues with the first or last amino acid (as mentioned in the comments), but for the most part, problem solved.